# Creating a specific paragraph style for tables in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I want to create a style specifically for tables. The problem I'm facing is that every time I create a new table or modify it, it switches to "Normal" instead of my "Table Text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access table styles in the Styles and Formatting task pane? After you create a new style there, you should be able to set it under the Table Autoformat dialog.

Comment: It's a paragraph style That I'm trying to append to my tables. The autoformat dialog only accept table styles. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

My research indicated that this is simply the way of the Word - I think I even found it documented on the Microsoft site, but can no longer find it. I created individual table paragraph fonts and applied them to the table styles, then made a note to the template users that they will likely have to re-apply them to the table anyway.

Comment: Thanks JenS for the answer, I found after that the best way to do it is to create 10/15 table classes each one of them represent a different table design. For example one will be with left columns different then body, one will be with left and top lines different etc.